# Why does it look like react is importing other files?

Tags: reactjs

So I have the directory with 2 files and an index.js:

```
Directory
-> FileA.js
-> FileB.js
-> Index.js
```

My index.js there looks like this:

```
import FileA from './FileA';
import FileB from './FileB';

export {
  FileA,
  FileB
};
```

Now in a Component I import FileA like so:
`import { FileA } from '@/Directory';`

However in FileB there is an issue as I removed a package. But I am not importing FileB. So how come I get an error complaining about a missing package in FileB when its not even being imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already importing it in your `index.js` therefore its used. you can directly export it like:

```
export {default as FileA} from './FileA';
export {default as FileB} from './FileB';
```

and it should help and work the same